# String replace without replacing / dividing numeric data

Tags: r, text, stringr

In R using stringr package to perform string replace. The text file has 2 headers, a row 1 header and a sub-header, row 2. I use read_lines(n_max=1) to get one row and skip=n to position unto the next row. I need a correct regex or pattern to keep numeric data (and date data) in place while replacing "|" only with comma ",".

```
dat_subheader <- read_lines("1999-0.txt", skip=1, n_max=1)
dat_row1 <- read_lines("1999-0.txt", skip=2, n_max=1)
```

```
[1] "# XD|A Code|S Code|C Code|Site ID|Parameter|POC|Sample Duration|Unit|Method|Date|Start Time|Sample Value|Null Data Code|Sampling Frequency|Monitor Protocol (MP) ID|Qualifier - 1|Qualifier - 2|Qualifier - 3|Qualifier - 4|Qualifier - 5|Qualifier - 6|Qualifier - 7|Qualifier - 8|Qualifier - 9|Qualifier - 10|Alternate Method|Uncertain"
```

```
[1] "# XC|A Code|S Code|C Code|Site ID|Parameter|POC|Unit|Method|Year|Period|Number of Samples|Composite Type|Sample Value|Monitor Protocol (MP) ID|Qualifier - 1|Qualifier - 2|Qualifier - 3|Qualifier - 4|Qualifier - 5|Qualifier - 6|Qualifier - 7|Qualifier - 8|Qualifier - 9|Qualifier - 10|Alternate Method |Uncertain"
```

List of data contents:

```
[1] "XD|I|01|027|0001|88101|1|7|105|120|19990103|00:00||AS|3|||||||||||||"
```

Now using function, str_replace_all, to attempt to replace all occurrences of "|" to a comma ",". My str_replce_all() is thus set:

```
str_replace_all(dat_row1, "|", ",")
```

But the result is replacing even the numeric data and dates with comma ",". I know I'm missing the correct pattern for this replace, need some helpful ideas. The vertical bar "|" only serves as a delimiter, and only this delimiter needs to be changed to comma ",". Would very much appreciate help in the right direction.

result showing incorrect replacements.

```
[1] ",X,D,|,I,|,0,1,|,0,2,7,|,0,0,0,1,|,8,8,1,0,1,|,1,|,7,|,1,0,5,|,1,2,0,|,1,9,9,9,0,1,0,3,|,0,0,:,0,0,|,|,A,S,|,3,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use escape character `\\`

```r
>str_replace_all("XD|I|01|027|0001|88101|1|7|105|120|19990103|00:00||AS|3|||||||||||||", "\\|", ",")
[1] "XD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990103,00:00,,AS,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
```

Comment: thanks, I completely forgot about escape char, even though I have used them before, I guess the pressure is on me ever since my wife forced me to cancel an in person interview, which I have been waiting to get for months...

Comment: No problem, even I have to try it twice as started with \ one not two of them. This is place to save some time mostly when we have this time pressure.

Comment: thanks, I enjoy the engagement help. I was working with AVATAR EPIC SQL before and found no solution to do a hierarchy query (not support SQL dialect in EPIC); the IT manager was not able to get it to work so he passed it onto me; basically to ensure that I would fail, it was sabotage at its finest. I offered alternative designs to offload the date, manipulate it in R, re-load, but IT managers rejected every alternative design idea. [County of Fresno]